# Sharing an encrypted home folder between Ubuntu and Kubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, installation, encryption

I have a drive partitioned into three sections: two small ones and one large one. (Let's call them partitions A, B, C).

Partition A has Ubuntu 9.10 installed on it, with partition C mounted as /home.
When I installed Ubuntu, I chose to encrypt my home folder.

Now, I'd like to isntall Kubuntu on partition B, and use the same home folder for both OSes.

How do I set up Kubuntu 9.10 to re-use the same folder, and give it the decryption key? (which I wrote down when I installed Ubuntu, of course).

Comment: why don't you just install the kubuntu desktop inside ubuntu?

Comment: Right, the Ubuntu docs site has good instructions on adding the Kubuntu to a default Ubuntu (=Kubuntu), and then turning it off at will (back to Gnome, but KDE apps are still available).  You may not need a full second install.  (Unless, of course, you do...)

Comment: So your question is a valid one but I agree with the above comments; Look here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE

Comment: Mostly, because I don't like to mix up my usable OS with my experimentation. I've found that updates, dist-upgrades, and whatnot tend to break when I experiment with alternate desktop environemnts/distros.
In the past, when I tried this, I got a whole mess. But your suggestion is encouraging. Maybe I'll try that again.

Comment: Oh, and one of the complications that just occurred to me, is that I can no longer access files in my /home folder from Windows... Didn't think of that when I encrypted the whole thing. After all, I couldn't even *remember* the last time I'd used Windows on this machine.

Comment: Okay, mixing Ubuntu and Kubuntu is a minor *disaster*.  
I still have ALL the applications I had under Ubuntu, PLUS the new ones, and knetwork-manager and network-manager (gnome) are fighting for control. Wallpaper and mouse cursor are a nightmare, and the DEs don't share keyboard, language and locale settings.  
Total mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a lot of details of this exposed here:
http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7568/

If you can't determine a reasonable answer to your question from the 3 pages of article there, maybe the author of the article can help.

Comment: Yeah, there's a LOT of info there. Thank FSM for weekends.